# How to apply templates to multiple `std::array`s?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have a set of sets where all the sizes are known at compile-time and will not be changed, and I want to pass this to a function.

Something akin to:

```cpp
void someFunction(
    std::tuple<std::array<float,SIZE1>,std::array<float,SIZE2>,std::array<float,SIZE3>> sets
) { 
    //...
}
```

With the number of inner `std:array`s being variable and all the sizes of the `std::array`s being variable.

Right now, I'm lost at where to start approaching this problem and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your intent for `someFunction` to be a template function? And do you really intend for this tuple to be passed by value?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will need to iterate over the sets so `std::tuple` is not ideal, `std::array` would be preferred but I was not sure if that was possible. It would more likely be passed by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you'd go with a variadic template for this:

```
template<std::size_t... sizes>
void someFunction(std::tuple<std::array<float,sizes>...> sets) { 
    // ...
}
```

The `...` will expand `std::array<float,sizes>` for all sizes inside the tuple

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution, which also works with older standards is to accept any type:

```
template<class T>
void someFunction(const T& sets)
```

Since you appear to be passing arrays which may be large, using indirection is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You clarified that you prefer having separate parameters. The difference between using a single tuple, versus discrete parameters, is not really that much. The following solution requires at least parameter, and enforces all parameters to be `std::array`s of the same size:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>

template<size_t i,
     typename ...T,
     typename=std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<
                   std::is_same<T, std::array<float, i>>...>>
     >
void someFunction(const std::array<float, i> &first,
          const T &...others)
{
}

void foo()
{
    someFunction(std::array<float, 5>{}); // OK.

    someFunction(std::array<float, 5>{},
             std::array<float, 5>{}); // OK.

    someFunction(std::array<float, 5>{},
             std::array<float, 10>{}); // ERROR.
}
```

Some of the traits are C++17 and higher, but can be trivially re-implemented in C++11 and C++14.

Comment: The function will take a considerable number of other parameters and it simply serves best to contain these sets in 1 parameter. The arrays also need to be able to differ in size. Apologies for not being as specific here as I should have been (I'm still messing around), sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, and it was a good mental excersize -- devise a way to enforce at compile time all arrays to be of the same size.